# Is it possible to disable form fields flattening

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign API for e-signature and DocuSign.eSign nuget package. 
I'm creating envelope from single PDF file.

However whenever I sign PDF document all my form fields are flatten.

When I use composite template PDF document is flatten before signing and if I not PDF document is flatten after signing (and I use tabs and recipients mapping).

I cannot find option for disabling such behavior.

Is it possible to control it or not?

Thanks,
Drasko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign flattens all PDFs to eliminate security threats from active PDF documents.

What is the underlying issue? You can transform PDF form fields into DocuSign fields (tabs). The tab values can later be retrieved from DocuSign as needed.

Comment: Thanks we planned complex workflow with one document and multiple stages for filling and signing.
For instance in first stage one user fills page one and 2 and sign it and then another user fills other pages and sign them.
But I agree, for security reasons this ways is the best. I was assuming it but needed confirmation.
So we'll have to split it, do the workflow and merge it again if this is supported?

Comment: Check out [document visibility](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility). If you have further questions, please open a new question here on StackOverflow. Thank you.